# Play Framework 2 Submodules and Javascript routes

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0

I have a play project with 3 submodules

- API ( /api )
- Admin ( /admin )
- SPA ( /spa )

I would like to expose my Javascript Routes using play's JavascriptRouter.

It works great for routes in the main project.

e.g.

```
public static Result jsRoutes()
 {
response().setContentType("text/javascript");
return ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("appRoutes", controllers.routes.javascript.Application.index()));
}
```

Although it does not work for the Controllers which are in my subprojects.

If I try this

```
controllers.api.routes.javascript
```

it returns only ReverseControllers but they show no Javascript reverse routes.

What am I doing wrong ? Any idea ?

controllers.api.routes.javascript shows all my controllers but no JS ones.

Thanks